# Delphi printing with Canvas, align text to the right

Tags: delphi, canvas, printing

I'm printing using `TPrinter.Canvas` and am trying to align the text to the right due to money displaying numbers.

The text is printed with this code:

```
Printer.Canvas.Textout(800, 100, 250.00); //charge1
Printer.Canvas.Textout(800, 200,  10.00); //charge2
Printer.Canvas.Textout(800, 300, 260.00); //Total Amount
```

[image: Sample image]

How can I align the lines to display correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the lower level device context Api's to more accurately control the text output, such as `DrawText()` as suggested by Jerry.  However, doing this will require that you pre-calculate/set the bounding rectangle for your text output so that Windows knows the area which any alignment is relative to.

There are two potentially simpler alternatives:

### Option 1 - For Fixed Width Fonts ONLY

This may be appropriate for you since you appear to be using a fixed-width font.

All we do here is introduce padding to your strings prior to output.  This may be simpler than the calculations required for the output rectangles etc.

To do this, decide on the longest string you will accept for output and then add whatever spaces you need to the left of each string to ensure they are all the same length.  With a fixed width font, a space takes up the same horizontal space as any other character so by making all strings the same length you will achieve "right alignment":

```
procedure PrintRightJustified(const aX, aY, aMaxLen: Integer; aValue: String);
var
  s: String;
begin
  s := aValue;

  // Pad the string with spaces to the maximum length
  if Length(s) < aMaxLen then
    s := StringOfChar(' ', aMaxLen - Length(s)) + s;

  Printer.Canvas.Textout(aX, aY, s);
end;
```

Then call this method to output your strings right-justified to a consistent maximum length, e.g. if 6 is your maximum length (999.99):

```
PrintRightJustified(800, 100, 6, '250.00'); //charge1
PrintRightJustified(800, 200, 6, '10.00'); //charge2
PrintRightJustified(800, 300, 6, '260.00'); //Total Amount
```

How to handle scenarios where the specified string is longer than the maximum width is left as an exercise.

### Option 2 - For Any Font

Another way, which would work for fixed width or variable width fonts (e.g. Arial) would be to choose the position of the rightmost edge of the strings and calculate the X position relative to this based on the device width calculated for each string you are outputting:

```
procedure PrintRightJustified(const aRightX, aY; aValue: String);
var
  leftX: Integer;
begin
  leftX := aRightX - Printer.Canvas.TextWidth(aValue);

  Printer.Canvas.Textout(leftX, aY, aValue);
end;
```

You don't need to specify a maximum width for this version, it works regardless of font being used:

```
PrintRightJustified(900, 100, '250.00'); //charge1
PrintRightJustified(900, 200, '10.00'); //charge2
PrintRightJustified(900, 300, '260.00'); //Total Amount
```

This does mean that text may potentially "bleed" too far to the left without some mechanism to detect and handle this.  Again, If that is a concern then either move the right-edge further across or you will have to come up with a way of handling it (left as an exercise for you since we don't know what your precise requirements are).

Comment: "...text may potentially "bleed" too far to the left..." AKA "Clipping". Easily handled using `DrawText` which works that way by default, in absence of `DT_NOCLIP`. The same applies for `TCanvas.TextOut()` in its normal nature. After all, `DrawText()` provides all the control we need. `TCanvas.TextOut()` is very limited.

Comment: FWIW, in Delphi versions with `System.SysUtils.TStringHelper`, you can do: `s := s.PadLeft(MaxLen);`.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using VCL's `TextOut`, you should use the Winapi [`DrawText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtext) and choose to align to the right using that within a given rectangle, specifically using `DT_RIGHT`. For example...

```
DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(T), Length(T), R, DT_SINGLELINE or DT_RIGHT);
```

Comment: Using this approach you should mention the need to calculate/set the bounding rectangle for the text to obtain the correct positioning in addition to the right-alignment.

Comment: @Deltics That all depends on what's required. Most of the time, you already know the area (Rect) in which you wish to draw the text. Obviously it would align with the right edge of the given rectangle. I expect OP to read the documentation which I linked and decide for themselves how to use it. Just a few hours ago, I wrote code using `DrawText` and had zero need to calculate anything - just pass a `TRect` of the area I need to draw in.

Comment: OP states that they are using `TextOut` which does not require any rect calculations.  If you could rely on OP to read documentation and extrapolate from that all that they need to learn for themselves and do so then they wouldn't be here asking this question in the first place now, would they ?  ;)

Comment: @Deltics I think you missed my point about reading the documentation, which is expected of *any* programmer. It's not that hard to see what arguments are required and abide by those rules. If it helps, I already edited my answer 9 minutes ago to include this...

Comment: I got your point very clearly.  I just don't understand why someone with that point (of view) would ever bother answering any question with anything other than "RTFM".  it certainly doesn't strike me as very helpful to provide an incomplete/partial answer and *then* shrug all else off with that.

Comment: @Deltics Again, 14 minutes ago, I edited my answer to include "within a given rectangle". Do you really expect me to write complete code for OP to copy/paste without learning anything? The idea is for OP to *learn* about what they're doing, not to have people write their code for them.

Comment: Canvas.TextRect uses DrawTextEx, accepts a TextFormat parameter.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Yet it's always beneficial to learn how things work on a lower level.

Comment: Yeah, anyway, with canvas should be like `Printer.Canvas.TextRect(R, T, [tfRight, tfSingleLine])`

Answer (score 0):

To Option 1 - For Fixed Width Fonts ONLY
First on word you check how many space you need to align your number. For Times I did need 2 spaces so you just double the procedure line:

```
s := StringOfChar(' ', aMaxLen - Length(s)) + s;
s := StringOfChar(' ', aMaxLen - Length(s)) + s;
```

Comment: Please edit your answer with proper spelling and code formatting. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To the precedent answer!
With the above given code (Answer 1) I couldn'get my number aligned with one space.
After some thinking, I check on Word with my font, Times New Roman, how many space I need to get the number aligned, (the decimal dot have to be vertically aligned).
I noticed that two spaces were necessary not only one.

I juste wrote the command two times:

```
s:= StringOfChar(' ', aMaxLen - Length(s)) + s;  
s:= StringOfChar(' ', aMaxLen - Length(s)) + s;
```

Man could do

```
s:= StringOfChar(' ', aMaxLen - Length(s))+ StringOfChar(' ', aMaxLen - 
Length(s)) + s;
```

Excuse my english but it is not my mother language.
I hope it is a bit more understandable.